# ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'ArtistID' doesn't have a default value while using stored procedure

Tags: mysql

1. Use the COUNT aggregate on Artists to see how many rows exist for NameOfArtist. Store the count in a variable called artist_count.
2. If artist_count is zero, insert a new row into Artists. Select the LAST_INSERT_ID() into a variable.
3. If artist_count is one, lookup the ArtistID and store it in a variable.
4. Insert a new row into the Albums table.

.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddAlbum (
  NameOfArtist varchar(50),
  AlbumName varchar(50)
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE artist_count INT;
  DECLARE artist_id INT;

  SELECT COUNT(ArtistName) INTO artist_count
  FROM Artists WHERE ArtistName = NameOfArtist;

  IF artist_count = 0
    THEN INSERT INTO Artists (ArtistName)
       VALUES(NameOfArtist);

       SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO artist_id;
  ELSEIF artist_count = 1
    THEN SELECT ArtistID INTO artist_id FROM Artists
         WHERE ArtistName = NameOfArtis;
  END IF;

  INSERT INTO Albums (Title)
    VALUES (AlbumName);
END;
//
```

This is the error I'm getting, when I call the procedure. I can't figure it out.

```
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'ArtistID' doesn't have a default value
```

Answer (score 1):

The error should be pretty self-explanatory. Your `Artists` table doesn't have any default value for the `ArtistID` column, so trying to insert just an `ArtistName` into it (for the `artist_count = 0` case) fails.

You should probably configure the `ArtistID` column as an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, since you don't care what the values are, so long as they're unique.

Comment: I checked that, it is auto_increment.

Comment: Hmm, how about the `Albums` table? Does it have an `ArtistID` column that you aren't passing a value for?

Comment: Yeah it does. I spoke with my instructor for the class.
Looks like the last insert statement needs to be this

>  >  > INSERT INTO Albums (ArtistID, Title)
 >  >  > VALUES (artist_id, AlbumName);
 >  >  > END;

Comment: I'm awful at making my posts look the way they need to. Sorry.